# Replace all strings in the form ".get_x()"?

Tags: regex

With regex how could I go about replacing all strings in the form:

```
.get_x()
```

With

```
.x
```

Ilspy has incorrectly decompiled an assembly and all of the properties have been replaced with get_ and set_ and a function call.

Comment: This is basic regex. Have you seen some tutorials?

Comment: I've looked at tutorials and I couldn't really find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace matches of `\.get_(\w+)\(\)` with `.\1`.

Note that depending on the tool you use you may need to use `$1` for the replacement instead of `\1`.  Obviously you can do something similar to replace the `.set_x()`, or you could do them both at once using the following regex:

```
\.[gs]et_(\w+)\(\)
```